# document.getElementsByName not finding the elements

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to get all the form elements on my page so I can add some hidden inputs to them however, when I try to find them, they are not being found:

```
window.onload = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName( 'form' ).length); # Output: 0
    console.log(document); # See below output
};
```

Output of the document log:

```
# Document
<html><head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="/v1/notify.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/test" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name...">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    
</body></html>
```

I can see on here, and on my HTML view, that there is in-fact a form there and the `document` does have that in there. Why can I not get this form with `document.getElementsByName()` ?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` gets the Elements by their HTML `name` attribute. If you want the Elements by their tag name use `document.getElementsByTagName`. But really, these days you can just use `document.querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `document.getElementsByTagName`.
This will give you an `HTMLCollection` - array-like, so you'll have to use an index for the form you want from "all" the forms: `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]`.
Even `document.getElementsByName` will give you a collection.
`document.getElementById` will get you a specific element, as long as you didn't use the same id more than once.
Now I'm going to hear about `querySelector`....
By the way, comment in javascript is `//`, not `#`, and a comment block starts with `/*` and ends with `*/`.